# How can I bring origin/HEAD to my current commit?

Tags: git, gitlab

In my local repo I am working in branch `main`. The same branch exists in my remote repo. Some time ago both branches were in sync, `origin/main` and `main` pointed to the same commits.

But then I maybe did something wrong. Since then `origin/main` and `origin/HEAD` don't move anymore. So my local `main` is ahead of the remote `origin/main`:

```
$ git log --oneline --all
eb11f1b (HEAD, main) Merge branch 'autoencoder' into main
(...)
(...) <-- I did several commits here
(...)
3b641f6 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) Merge branch 'predict_big_data' into 'main'
```

However, all my files are in sync between local and remote.

```
$ git status
On branch main
```

(I have some uncommited files, but shouldn't worry here)

Nothing seems to be broken, just that `origin/HEAD` is still pointing to commit 3b641f6.

```
$ git fetch origin
From ssh://[...]
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

```
$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

I've read so many things online but I get more and more confused. Either it didn't change anything, or I fear to destroy anything.

Do you have any suggestions what I could do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to push.

Comment: I did it already - added it to the question

Comment: Why you need alter value of `origin/HEAD`? Note `HEAD` has special meaning (currently checkout version), so there is no reason `origin/HEAD` should follow local `HEAD`. Just ignore this diffrence

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1192881/726817

Comment: Ok, I've read this (and more), but I still don't quite understand the issue. To me it still seems not to be the perfect situation that I'm having. Ok, I can live with it, but supposed I want to change it anyway? Would calling `git remote set-head origin main` be the solution? Or do I destroy anything with it?